# kinect v2 change the kinectCursor's size and image

Tags: cursor, kinect

[image]

How to change the kinect hand's size ?

My program is running in a large resolution screen, so I couldn't even see the kinectCursor.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your KinectRegion is named FooRegion. You can change how it renders hand cursor pretty easily:

```
FooRegion.CursorSpriteSheetDefinition = new CursorSpriteSheetDefinition(FooUri, numColumns, numRows, iconWidth, iconHeight);
```

Where FooUri is Uri to a bitmap. This bitmap consists of images of size (in pixels I believe) iconWidth x iconHeight. These images are arranged in a numColumns x numRows grid. They need to be in correct order so that when FooRegion crops this bitmap to get a cursor image it needs at a given time it gets apropriate one. Kinect Wpf samples from Kinect SDK browser can provide a reference spritesheet if you need.

CursorSpriteSheetDefinition resides in Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Input.